# How can I use the bind_param() with multiple params

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, bindparam

So I have a table with the colums title,description,created, fk_u.
Then I have this statement:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare( "insert into blogs1(title,description,created,fk_u) values(?,?,?,?)");
```

Afterwards I try to bind the parameters with bind_param().

```
$stmt->bind_param("ssii", $title,$desc,NOW(),$id);
```

The Problem I get is that it dosen't recognise the NOW() function. 
What could be the error. Am I using the bind_param function wrong?

Comment: `NOW()` is not a PHP function, it's a MySQL function. It does not need to be bound since it's not user data. Just add it directly into your query.

Comment: True. I should have come up with that solution myself. But thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NOW()` is MySQL, so move this to your SQL and remove the bind...

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare( "insert into blogs1(title,description,created,fk_u) 
                  values(?,?,NOW(),?)");

$stmt->bind_param("ssi", $title,$desc,$id);
```